# Can I use imenu-mode in buffers which do not contain function definitions?

Tags: emacs

It appears that imenu does not index normal buffers (like plain text), but indexes function definitions in a code buffer(in a java file, for example).

Whenever I run <kbd>M-x</kbd>`imenu`, it says

`Index item:`

but cannot find anything in the current buffer. I feel I am using it the wrong way, but could not find anything on this on the web.

Below is a screenshot.[image]

Comment: You can have `imenu` buffers without function definitions. You will need to customize the variable `imenu-generic-expression` with proper parameters. You can read the documentation by doing `C-h v`imenu-generic-expression`RET`.

Comment: Generally, imenu can index anything and not just functions (try it in an `M-x man` buffer), but a major mode needs to add  specific support for imenu.  If it doesn't, imenu will not work, unless you configure it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to have function definitions in a buffer to be able to use `imenu`. However in this case you will need to tell it how you want to index the items. One way (and in my opinion the simplest) is to use the variable `imenu-generic-expression`. It is basically a list of parameters that instruct `imenu` how to create indexes. Each parameter has a particular format. You can read the documentation of the variable (and the format of parameters) by doing <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>`imenu-generic-expression`<kbd>RET</kbd>.

Below is a simple example that can be used in shell mode buffers, to index environment variables assignments.

```
(setq imenu-generic-expression '((nil "^\\([A-Z_]+\\)=.*" 1)))
```

The above expression instructs `imenu`

1) To search for string matching `"^\\([A-Z_]+\\)=.*"`

2) Use the first matched sub-expression in the regexp as an imenu index

3) The first element nil means that the imenu items given expression should be at top level index

You can set this up in shell-mode buffers by adding something like the following to your init file (don't do this see the edit below)

```
(add-hook 'sh-mode-hook (lambda ()
                      (setq imenu-generic-expression '((nil "^\\([A-Z_]+\\)=.*" 1)))))
```

**EDIT**

`sh-mode` does provide imenu indexing but it is limited to function definitions (thanks @lunaryorn for pointing this out) for pointing this out. You can combine the imenu provided by imenu with you custom regexp by doing something like the following

```
(defun my-shell-mode-setup-imenu ()
  (setq imenu-generic-expression (append '((nil "^\\([A-Z_]+\\)=.*" 1)) 
                                         (nthcdr 1 (car sh-imenu-generic-expression)))))

(add-hook 'sh-mode-hook 'my-shell-mode-setup-imenu)
```

Comment: Hi @lunaryorn, I did not check thoroughly but `M-x imenu` did not give me any results.

Comment: OK just checked it supports only shell function definitions, I will update the answer. The user can still combine `sh-imenu-generic-expression` with regexp above to get better results. Thanks for the correction

Comment: @Iqbal explained it well.  Imenu is, in general, for anything you might like to condider a **definition**. Even more generally, it is for navigating among places that match any set of (regexp-based) patterns you like.